# Why does my Jupyter Notebook work on one computer and fail on another?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I have recently downloaded Jupyter Notebook into my mac but the file that I was able to open in my school windows gives me an error.

These are my libraries:

```
# Basic Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # we only need pyplot
sb.set() # set the default Seaborn style for graphics

# Import essential models and functions from sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

(I believe I have downloaded all the libraries into my laptop)

This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

SalePrice = pd.DataFrame(data['SalePrice'])
GrLivArea = pd.DataFrame(data['GrLivArea'])

# split for train and test
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(GrLivArea, SalePrice, test_size = 0.25)

linReg = LinearRegression()
linReg.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
regX = xtrain
regY = linReg.intercept_ + linReg.coef_ * xtrain

# prints coefficients
print('Intercept \t: b = ', linReg.intercept_)
print('Coefficients \t: a = ', linReg.coef_)

# plot the first graph
f = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.scatter(xtrain, ytrain)
plt.plot(regX, regY, 'r-', linewidth = 3)
plt.show()

# plot the second graph
trainPred = linReg.predict(xtrain)
testPred  = linReg.predict(xtest)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.scatter(xtrain, ytrain)
plt.scatter(xtrain, trainPred, color = "r")
plt.show()
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
     20 f = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
     21 plt.scatter(xtrain, ytrain)
---> 22 plt.plot(regX, regY, 'r-', linewidth = 3)
     23 plt.show()
     25 # plot the second graph

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:487, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    484         kw[prop_name] = val
    486 if len(xy) == 2:
--> 487     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
    488     y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489 else:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py:1327, in _check_1d(x)
   1321 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
   1322     warnings.filterwarnings(
   1323         "always",
   1324         category=Warning,
   1325         message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
-> 1327     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328     # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329     # cast to a numpy array.
   1330     if len(w) > 0:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3628, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3623         raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624     except TypeError:
   3625         # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626         #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627         #  the TypeError.
-> 3628         self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3629         raise
   3631 # GH#42269

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5637, in Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5633 def _check_indexing_error(self, key):
   5634     if not is_scalar(key):
   5635         # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5636         # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5637         raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

Does anyone know whats wrong? I feel like I have to download more libraries into my laptop (..?) because my code works on the school computer. Please help.

Comment: Are you certain that your using the same Python versions and module versions in both computers? That might be an explanation in case anything changed in one of your dependencies